# Mvc EditorTemplate for List<string> with dynamic amount

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, mvc-editor-templates

I've made a simple EditorTemplate for a list in my Model (Views/Shared/EditorTemplates/List.cshtml):

```
@model List<string>
foreach (var str in Model)
{
    <li>
        @Html.LabelFor(m => str, "My Label")
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => str)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => str)
    </li>
}
```

Called like this in my view (Views/Profile.cshtml):

```
@using (Html.BeginRouteForm(MvcSettings.SitecoreRouteName, FormMethod.Post, new { data_abide = "true", id = "myForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.Sitecore().FormHandler("User", "UpdateProfile")
    @Html.ValidationSummary()

    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "listTestId" } })

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

Controlled Action:

```
public ActionResult UpdateProfile(IntranetContactViewModel formModel)
{
    // Save information to DB
}
```

Model:

```
public class IntranetContactViewModel
{
    public List<string> ListTest { get; set; }

    public IntranetContactViewModel()
    {
        ListTest = new List<string>{"abc","def","ghi"};
    }
}
```

When the list contains 3 strings then the view will render me 3 text-boxes.

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="listTestId" name="ListTest[0]" type="text" value="abc">
<input class="text-box single-line" id="listTestId" name="ListTest[1]" type="text" value="def">
<input class="text-box single-line" id="listTestId" name="ListTest[2]" type="text" value="ghi">
```

But, the amount of options the user can insert should be unlimited. If all 3 text-boxes are filled in a 4th should appear (And, ideally, if more than 2 text-boxes are empty, 1 should be deleted).

I tried doing this myself by adding a text-box with the same signature ( added 1 to the counter inside the name attribute )

```
<input class="text-box single-line" id="listTestId" name="ListTest[3]" type="text" value="TEST">
```

But when I submit this, this doesn't get recognized by the Model and isn't returned to the Controller.
Is there a way to let my Model know that it now also needs to keep track of this new text-box? Or is this simply not possible?

Please advise.

Comment: Can we see a bit more code - form definition and controller function that receives it?  Also, have you checked that it is definitely being posted back by examining the contents of the POST that the browser sends?

Comment: The model might be useful too then

Comment: Edits were made. It seems like that browser did pick up on the new field and added it to the POST .

Comment: I'm surprised a foreach loop actually generates that - I don't know how it gets the index to create "ListTest[0]" in the name attribute etc.  I normally loop with a counter and use the counter in the lambdas

Comment: There are so many questions on SO and so many articles on the web about this. Read this, for example: http://www.mattlunn.me.uk/blog/2014/08/how-to-dynamically-via-ajax-add-new-items-to-a-bound-list-model-in-asp-mvc-net/

Comment: Why do you give the same id to all the editors? That could be the problem.

Comment: I did not. That's created by the MVC EditorTemplate system. EDIT: ow i see. I meant for the entire structure to get that id, not all individual textboxes. I'll change that now

Comment: I can see in your code that you are assigning the id. `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "listTestId" } })`.

Comment: Replace that with `@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListTest)` to see what happens.

Comment: What do you mean by entire structure? There's no entire structure.

Comment: That was indeed what was the problem. Once i removed the " new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "listTestId" } } " My problems were solved. I figured the id would be given to a control around the textboxes. But that wasn't the case at all and i didn't pick up on it. Call it stupid friday afternoon mistakes. Thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListTest, new { htmlAttributes = new { id = "listTestId" } })
```

Should have been:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.ListTest)
```

I forced all my text-boxes to get the same id, and this screwed up the system.
Thanks to everyone in the comments for helping out!